# How do I get all the products in an E-Commerce website developed in Magento

Tags: products, product-list

How do I get all the products in an E-Commerce website developed in Magento?

Note: I am not the developer of the website, I am a student who is wondering if i can get all the products in that site listed at one place.

**Edit 1:**
Lot of Answers have given me solutions from the backend, but I want to know if it is possible from the front-end, for example, for websites built with OpenCart if you go to the search bar and type a single space and search, it will list all the products sold by that E-Commerce Website, I want to know if such a hack exists for Magento Websites.

Another example would be websites built with WooCommerce, if you enter the domain-name/products or domain-name/shop it will take you to the page which lists all the products, I am asking if there is such a method in Magento too. Lot of people put this question on hold siting the question was too general hope this edit gives them an idea about what I am exactly looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import & Export all categories using csv file (without extension)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86113/import-export-all-categories-using-csv-file-without-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Create File in Root

```
magento/productcoll.php

<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);
ini_set('post_max_size', '5000M');
ini_set("memory_limit","4046M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5000M');
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
{
   echo $_product->getStatus().'</br>';

       echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
       echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
       echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
       echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // for remove Area code is not set error
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
foreach ($collection as $product)
{
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For magento 1, you can export all the products with help of backend....

Go to **System > Import/Export > Data Profile > click on Export All Products > click on Run profile > Run Profile in pop up**.

you can get the excel sheet with all products information saved in server......